# Is it common to use "output" as a verb?

Tags: word-usage

At work (in some code) I encountered the word "output" being used as a verb and was a bit confused at first, because I misread it as a noun. I have never seen this usage before and for some reason it seems very strange to me, but then I am not a native speaker.

I checked the dictionary and "to output" is indeed listed, but there is no mention of the commonness.

So, is this usage common or rare? Should I change the word or keep it?

Comment: It is perfectly fine and has been forever. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/output#Verb), [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/output), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/output), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/output)...

Comment: @RegDwigнt It is however, strongly discouraged, almost deprecated in formal writing, what with writers' experiments with *outputted* (listed in dictionaries but not recommended); the suggested method being to use a separate verb with tense along with *output* as noun (*generated output* .)